# How S3 versioning different from Git?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, versioning

[Git](https://git-scm.com/) is used as file(non-binary) versioning tool. Git is a distributed version control tool

JFrog is used for binary files versioning

How [S3 versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html) different from Git and JFrog?

Comment: They are different tools altogether, there are comparisons sure i.e. versioning is like Git with commit history etc. but they are essentially providing different functionality.  It's like anything, many tools might have "similar" aspects but realistically they are not the same tool and can't be used as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, they are similar. Both [Git](https://book.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) and [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html) with versioning enabled store snapshots and hashes of objects. Actually, Git is a lot more similar to S3 then the other VCSes, like SVN or Mercurial because they only store diffs (deltas) between revisions not snapshots.

But that's it. Git and S3 / JFrog (Artifactory, Bintray) are completely different:

- Git is a local tool and you access it by operating on files (either with its CLI or 3rd party tools). S3 and Artifactory are remote object storages and you access them via HTTP / REST API (their CLIs are just wrappers around HTTP API).
- S3 is more low level. Basically it's just an object storage, like filesystem, with simple CRUD-like operations. Git provides a lot [more functionality](https://git-scm.com/docs) that operate on content and allow effective collaboration. JFrog tools are more about distribution of the artifacts.
- Git is open source, S3 and Artifactory are proprietary (however there is a [community edition for Artifacoty](https://jfrog.com/open-source/) as well as [open source implementations of S3 protocol](https://www.minio.io/)).

> Git is used as file (non-binary) versioning tool.

Git has an [LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) (Large File Storage) extension that can be used to store binary content externally thus making Git suitable for versioning binary files. And some of LFS [implementations](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Implementations) actually use S3 as actual object storage (back to the statement that Git is more high level)

S3 [can also be used as a file store](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+the+Filestore) for Artifactory.

Comment: yes, branching and merging is something related, when we work for projects. S3 is also providing collaboration, for multi-user uploads.

Comment: Huh, git doesn't store diffs/deltas between revisions, it uses snapshots (content addressed merkle trees).

Comment: @PhilippMildenberger does it somehow contradicts my answer? Or proves it?

Comment: Ah I think I have misread the answer in that git does store diffs (while you meant SVN etc.). No in that case all good, sorry for the noise.